# PHP get cookie value

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

I create a cookie with javascript with this code:

```
$('#solicita').click(function(){
  document.cookie = 'courseId=<?php echo $course[id]?>';
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

This create a cookie with the name courseId with a value.
Then I'm trying to read the cookie with the following php code:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['courseId'])) {
 $course   = ORM::for_table('courses')->find_one($_COOKIE['courseId']);
 ...
}
```

but isset($_COOKIE['courseId'] is always false. This code was working until last week that I change my .htaccess in order to have a friendly links. This is the code I added to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /peppers/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cp/artes-escenicas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/ciencia-y-tecnologia/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/arte-y-diseno/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/deportes/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/idiomas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/academico/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/rutas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/voluntariado/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Some help please

UPDATE

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not obvious how anything in your mod_rewrite directives might have disabled your cookie. Have you tried: `if ($_COOKIE['courseId'] != '') {echo '<p>courseId cookie contains '.$_COOKIE['courseId'].'</p>';} else {echo '<p>courseId Cookie is empty'</p>';}` just to check the contents of your cookie?

Comment: Yes, tried that code and I always get "courseId Cookie is empty"

Comment: Are you seeing the cookie in your developer console e.g. Firebug?

Comment: Yes I can see the cookie with the value

Comment: So your local browser can see the cookie, but your remote server can't?

Comment: @Rounin i just attached two image

Comment: Is your PHP script under the same path that the document that the cookie was set in was under? You can see in your screenshot that your cookie has a path value of `/peppers/cp/artes-escenicas` – so it will only be _send_ by your browser when you request an URL that begins with that same path. If you want it to be send for other resources outside of that path as well, then you have to _specify_ a less restrictive path when setting that cookie.

Comment: @CBroe, the php script that call the cookie is on http://localhost:8888/peppers/cp/home.php and the javascript that create the cookie it's on http://localhost:8888/peppers/cp/category/course-name, category and course-name can change from when the user make click

Comment: Yes, so the reason why your PHP script does not “see” that cookie is exactly as I said. So, go specify a path with your cookie. Please _research_ this, if you don’t know how that’s done.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I did not know anything about cookie with path. This is how I solve the problem document.cookie = 'courseId=<?php echo $course[id]?>; path=/'; if you post the answer I'll give you the check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are limited to a certain path, and will only be send again by the browser if the requested URL lies within that path.

You can see in your screenshot that your cookie has a path value of `/peppers/cp/artes-escenicas`. When setting a cookie via JavaScript, the path defaults to the path of the document that the script setting is cookie is running in.

If you want it to be send for other resources outside of that path as well, then you have to specify a less restrictive path when setting that cookie.